# SQL Server 2008: How do you convert an XML variable into tabular data?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

Say I have this XML variable:

```
declare @xml xml='< Employee EmployeeId="1" FirstName="John" LastName="Smith" />  
< Employee EmployeeId="2" FirstName="Jack" LastName="Brown" />  
< Employee EmployeeId="3" FirstName="Albert" LastName="Gordon" />  
< Employee EmployeeId="4" FirstName="Kate" LastName="White" />'
```

And a table with this structure:

```
EmployeeId (int)  
FirstName varchar(50)  
LastName varchar(50)
```

How do you populate it? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT 
    tab.col.value('@EmployeeId','int'),
    tab.col.value('@FirstName','varchar(50)'),
    tab.col.value('@LastName','varchar(50)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Employee') as tab(col)
```

Comment: I just have to +1 your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do you populate it?

Assuming you mean the table and not the xml.

```
insert into YourTable (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName)
select 
  e.value('@EmployeeId', 'int'),
  e.value('@FirstName', 'varchar(50)'),
  e.value('@LastName', 'varchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('Employee') as n(e)
```

Comment: +1 Any particular advantage or disadvantage to using `Employee` rather than `/Employee` or is it much the same?

Comment: a few seconds too late ;-) Thanks for answering though. Just one question: wouldn't it be slightly better to have /Employee in the nodes statement as opposed to just Employee?

Comment: @Martin, @Anthony – I don't think there will be any difference at all other than that it is clearer what you mean when using `/Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this way too

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

CREATE TABLE #Fields(Field varchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Fields
SELECT 
    x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)

SELECT * FROM #Fields
DROP TABLE #Fields
```